# Nifi:scheduling processor one day one flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to fetch online service with user Id-s(*for example from 1 to 100*)

I have put 3 parameters **start =1, end=100, parameter= 1**, in **GenerateFlowFile** after that i wrote groovy code in **exeucutescript** processor in a way that it generates 100 flowfile with certain user id-s i want to schedule my processor in a way that it can process only one flowfile in a day and retrieve only one user id in a day,i have

**Workflow look like this:**

**GenerateFlowFile->ExecuteScript->InvokeHttp->putFile**

I tried to change Back Pressure Object Threshold from 10000 to 1 but it doesn't work properly**. **What should i change to make this task?**

Answer (score 2):

the following works fine

- after generate flow file set backpressure 1
- after generate 100 files set backpressure 1
- for service call set execution once a day (timer or cron)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So what you need is a loop that will give you flowfile to drive your app.

[image]

Also see Nifi template here:
http://www.aodba.com/create-loop-apache-nifi/

Sorry for not going into details here but the template will be self explanatory.

I will also go in more detail in the post.

Comment: what  is  1d  scheudli   does  it mean  that  processor  works  only  one time in a day?